# How to perform inexact matches on two data sets

Tags: ms-access, duplicates

i'm trying to compare two data sets (vendor masters) from two systems. we are moving to one system, so we want to avoid duplication. the issue is that the names, addresses, etc could be slightly different. for example, the name might end in 'Inc' or 'Inc.' or the address could be 'St' or 'Street'. the vendor masters have been dumped to excel, so i was thinking about pulling them into access to compare them, but i'm not sure how to handle the inexact matches. the data fields i need to compare are: name, address, telephone number, feder tax id (if populated), contact name

Comment: But what is your questions? This website is designed to ask specific development questions, not open-ended "advise". It seems that the primary question might be about performing inexact matches on a set of data. More important to that question would be what you mean by "system" --is it all in Excel now? And what will the combined "system" be like? Access would only be for matching?  Don't just list a few columns with "etc.", rather list out exactly which **key** columns you'll need matching on.  Update the question to instead be something like "How to perform inexact matches on two data sets".

Comment: i'm sorry. this was my first time posting a question, so i didn't realize i was asking an open ended question. yes, i would like to know how to perform inexact matches on two data sets. i appreciate your time.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Sometimes you'll get some blunt answers, but you'll find everyone very helpful as you learn to formulate questions in a concise manner. Learning to do so should also help you focus on key _steps_ in solving a problem. This sort of problem that you posted will likely be a multi-part problem not answered by a single questions. You can edit this question and add some of the details I mentioned. Go ahead and update the question with more details about key fields AND how many records you will be comparing. Besides Access, what other tools / languages are you familiar with?

Comment: Okay. I updated the title and the detail. I use Oracle SQL and Access. Thank you for walking me through the process.

Comment: IMO, what you want to do is monumental and virtually impossible to code. No matter how you code it, will require case-by-case review with human eyes to evaluate and determine if record for J. J. Smith, Main St is for the same person as record for James J. Smith, Main Street. This is why you might get multiple copies of a newsletter, database has you in various records and the info is not exact duplicate so hard to find and purge and also why newsletters have contact info for 'if you receive duplicates, tell us which to stop'.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. That's what I was afraid of. We are basically comparing 11,000 vendors in one system to 10,000 vendors in another system and trying to avoid duplication. I am at a loss for how to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would proceed.  You will rarely get answers like this on Stack Exchange, since your question if not focused enough.  This is a rather generic set of steps not specific to a particular tool (i.e. database or spreadsheet). As I said in my comments, you'll need to search for specific answers (or ask new ones) about the particular tools you use as you go.  Without knowing all the details, Access can certainly be useful in doing some preliminary matching, but you could also utilize Excel directly or even Oracle SQL since you have it as a resource.

- Back up your data.
- Make a copy of your data for matching purposes.
- Ensure that each record for both sets of data have a unique key (i.e. AutoNumber field or similar), so that until you have a confirmed match the records can always be separately identified.
- Create new matched-key table and/or fields containing the list of matched unique key values.
- Create new "matching" fields and copy your key fields into these new fields.
- **Scrub** the data in all possible *matching* fields by

  - Removing periods and other punctuation
  - Choosing standard abbreviations and replacing all variations by the same value in all records. Example: replace "Incorporation" and "Inc." with "Inc"
  - Trim excess spaces from the end and between terms
  - Formatted all phone numbers exactly the same way, or better yet remove all space and punctuation for comparison purposes, excluding extension information: ##########
  - Parse and split multi-term fields into separate fields.  Name -> First, Middle, Last Name fields;  Address -> Street number, street name, extra address info.

    - The parsing process itself can identify and reconcile formatting differences.
    - Allows easier matching on terms separately.
  - Etc., etc.

Once the matching fields are sufficiently scrubbed, now match on the different fields.

- Define matching priorities, that is which field or fields are likely to produce reliable matches with the least amount of uncertainty.

  - For records containing Tax ID numbers, that seems like the most logical place to start since an exact match on that number should be valid OR can indicate mistakes in your data.
- For each type of match, update the matched-key fields mentioned above
- For each successive matching query, exclude records that already have a match in the matched-key table/fields.
- Refine and repeat all these steps until you are satisfied that all matches have been found.
- Add all non-matched records to your final merged record set.

You never said how many records you have.  If possible, it may be worth your organization's time to manually verify the automated matches by listing them side by side and manually tweaking them when needed.

But even if you successfully pair non-exact matches, someone still needs to make the decision of which record to keep for the merged system.  I imagine you might have matches on company name and tax id--essentially verifying the match--but still have different addresses and/or contact name.  There is no technical answer that will help you know which data to keep or discard. Once again, human review should be done to finalize the merged records.  If you set this up correctly, a couple human eyeballs could probably go through thousands of record in just a day.

Comment: I don't disagree with June7's sentiments. Especially if you have never done this before, it can indeed be daunting.  On the other hand, I have done this over and over before in various jobs on different systems.  No, you will not find any magic code that will do this for you in a few steps or in any automated manner.  But if you define a set of steps as I have done and develop the proper set of queries (both select and update queries), it can be completed efficiently.  Good luck!

Comment: Your approach makes sense and I greatly appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. I will make sure I follow the etiquette for this site before asking another question. Thanks again!